# React customHook using useEffect with async

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a customHook with using useEffect and I would like it to return a result once useEffect is done, however, it always return before my async method is done...

```
// customHook
const useLoadData = (startLoading, userId, hasError) => {
  const [loadDone, setLoadDone] = useState(false);
  const loadWebsite = async(userId) => {
     await apiService.call(...);
     console.log('service call is completed');
     dispatch(someAction);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // define async function inside useEffect
    const loadData = async () => {
       if (!hasError) {
          await loadWebsite();
       }
    }

    // call the above function based on flag
    if (startLoading) {
       await loadData();
       setLoadDone(true);
    } else {
      setLoadDone(false);
    }
  }, [startLoading]);

  return loadDone;
}

// main component
const mainComp = () => {
   const [startLoad, setStartLoad] = useState(true);
   const loadDone = useLoadData(startLoad, 1, false);
   useEffect(() => {
       console.log('in useEffect loadDone is: ', loadDone);
       if (loadDone) {
          // do something
          setStartLoad(false); //avoid load twice
       } else {
          // do something
       }
   }, [startLoad, loadDone]);
   useAnotherHook(loadDone); // this hook will use the result of my `useLoadData` hook as an execution flag and do something else, however, the `loadDone` always false as returning from my `useLoadData` hook
}
```

It seems in my useDataLoad hook, it does not wait until my async function `loadData` to be finished but return `loadDone` as false always, even that I have put `await` keyword to my `loadData` function, and `setLoadDone(true)` after that, it still returns false always, what would be wrong with my implementation here and how could I return the value correct through async method inside customHook?

Comment: The function you pass to `useEffect` isn't `async`, so I'm surprised you wouldn't get some kind of compiler error indicating that it needs to be `async` to be able to use `await`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Hi, my function defined inside `useEffect` is `loadData` which will be calling an async function `loadWebsite`, why does it not consider as no async?

Comment: Not `loadData`, the first parameter you're passing to `useEffect`. It's not 'async`.

Answer (score 0):

Well...it seems to be working after I put the `setLoadDone(true);` inside my async method, not inside `useEffect`, although I am not sure why...
updated code:

```
// customHook
const useLoadData = (startLoading, userId, hasError) => {
  const [loadDone, setLoadDone] = useState(false);
  const loadWebsite = async(userId) => {
     await apiService.call(...);
     console.log('service call is completed');
     dispatch(someAction);
     setLoadDone(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // define async function inside useEffect
    const loadData = async () => {
       if (!hasError) {
          await loadWebsite();
       }
    }

    // call the above function based on flag
    if (startLoading) {
       await loadData();
       // setLoadDone(true); doesn't work here
    }
  }, [startLoading]);

  return loadDone;
}
```

Comment: You still have a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. The call to `await loadData` is not correct here, you can't `await` it.